# Join two large tables in Tez

Tags: performance, hadoop, hive, tez, bigdata

Are there any recommendations to speed up query performance for joining two very large hive tables (> 2 TB) ? Execution engine used is Tez . Both the tables are unpartitioned and in text format. Cluster is having 64 nodes with 128 GB ram each.

Comment: The smaller the data volumes, the faster the query - therefore, columnar.

Comment: thanks Dudu...are you suggesting to use columnar data format for the tables like Parquet or ORC ?

Comment: Definitely. In addition -https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Vectorized+Query+Execution.  (Currently for ORC, I think there is a similar project for Parquet)